# Circular dependency: Magento\Logging\Model\Handler\Controllers depends on Magento\Logging\Model\Handler\Controllers and vice versa

Tags: magento-upgrade, magento2.3.2

***When i upgrade magento from 2.1.9 to 2.2.0 to 2.2.6 to 2.3.2 i am facing an issue Circular dependency:***

> Magento\Logging\Model\Handler\Controllers depends on
>   Magento\Logging\Model\Handler\Controllers and vice versa. when i
>   execute setup:upgrade command from terminal

Comment: Guys, If you have an answer please post it so that I can know it's a duplicate question but without posting don't mark it has a duplicate.

Comment: Hi, did you got solution on this @gajj

Comment: @ShajithaBanu There is an issue with Xtento module and After upgrading the issue got resolved.

Comment: From 2.3.2 to 2.3.3 need to upgrade?

Comment: NO, I have updated the Xtento module 3rd party so after that issue got fixed.